# Unlock FBA User

Tags: forms-authentication, user-accounts

Two days ago I was debugging some of my webpart which do password encryption, which I intentionally filled wrong FBA user password many times.

At first I thought it was just 15 minutes or so account locked, but until today, I still can't log in as FBA. And I thought it was my webpart fault, but I try it (filled up wrong password many times) in my backup server, it resulted the same, could not login as FBA.

I already try to log into the sql server and rewrite the FBA password, but still nothing happened.

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008.

Is there any way to reset things manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL FBA DB we have one column as Locked(I do not remember the name exactly). It is of boolean type and you need to set it false. Then the user will be unlocked.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was in asp_membership table which has column IsLockedOut. Thank you again.

Comment: yes...Sorry, it skipped from my mind to mention the Table name.